# Error while compiling, (using a 3rd party header file.) (olcPixelGameEngine) in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: c++, g++, c++17, header-files, olcpixelgameengine

I am using a header file named OlcPixelGameEngine, and one more header file, but when I run the compile command, I get a big error.

This is the command to compile the cpp program.

```
g++ main.cpp -o main -luser32 -lgdi32 -lopengl32 -lgdiplus -lShlwapi -lstdc++fs -static -std=c++17 -lxinput9_1_0 -lole32 -loleaut32 -ldinput8 -ldxguid -ldwmapi
```

and this is the error:-

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -luser32
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdi32
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopengl32
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdiplus
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lShlwapi
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxinput9_1_0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lole32
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -loleaut32
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldinput8
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldxguid
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldwmapi
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am using Linux, Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: You seem to be compiling Windows stuff on Linux. Libraries like -lgdi32 are probably Windows specific libraries.

Comment: Well, I have checked in my arch Linux distro that the program works, so I think the libraries are ported for Linux too.

Comment: I don't understand what you say? Where did you check again in Linux that the program works? Maybe it works because it used different compilation command than the one you are using.

Comment: https://github.com/gorbit99/olcPGEX_Gamepad
over here it states, the compile command should be same in Linux and Windows, therefore that command should be able to compile my program in Linux, but it needs libraries that I don't have.

Comment: Can you try compiling without any of those libraries? Remove these libraries and try: -luser32 -lgdi32 -lgdiplus -lShlwapi -lxinput9_1_0 -lole32 -loleaut32 -ldinput8 -ldxguid -ldwmapi

Comment: when I do that it gives me that it cant find the libraries needed

Comment: Which libraries are needed after removal of those libraries from the compilation command?

Comment: all of them, are needed, all of the libraries.

Comment: On this link (https://github.com/OneLoneCoder/olcPixelGameEngine/blob/dbeabb8ffc0b95d76993eeb1160eafc4de998cb9/olcPixelGameEngine.h#L73), there is a comment at the top, read it. It may help.

Comment: I am using the olc Pixel Head File, and also I am using one of its contributions 
https://github.com/gorbit99/olcPGEX_Gamepad
these libraries are needed for the second header file not the first, btw I know how to compile the first header file, but not the second one

Comment: Well if it doesn't work for Linux (as per the assumption they have stated in their README), you can just raise an issue on that repo.